# Protractor tests with React.js application slow to launch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, protractor

I'm using Protractor to e2e test my React.js application. I've set up protractor config file to ignore Angular synchronization.

```
...
onPrepare: function () {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
}
...
```

The issue is Protractor still waits for 11 seconds before launching the tests. Is there a way to cut down that waiting time?

**Edit**

It seems the problem is not my Protractor config at all, but a conflict with LiveReload. The Chrome instance launched by Protractor doesn't have LiveReload enabled but it is in my dev server configuration, which causes the browser to load waiting for LiveReload until it times out (then my tests start).

Answer (score 1):

You may try to tweak the [`allScriptsTimeout`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts-from-protractor) protractor configuration setting:

```
allScriptsTimeout: 1000,  // im milliseconds
```

Comment: Relevant, but it seems it was not the issue in my case.

Comment: @FelixD. thanks, consider posting an answer if the mystery is solved.